# What is the concurrency limit for GCD Dispatch groups?

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

I've been using a `DispatchGroup` to facilitate a number of concurrent calls in my app.

My backend team noticed that when I tried to make eight concurrent calls, they were separated into two batches of four calls.

1. Is four concurrent calls the limit for GCD?
2. Is this a limitation of the GCD framework, or is this dependent on the hardware?
3. Is there a way to allow for more concurrent calls?

Comment: 4 might be the limit for network call. not sure. Can you test the GCD alone with some other task?

Comment: My experience shows that `DispatchQueue` maxes out at 62 concurrent tasks. Specialty queues may have their own limits. This is just anecdotal evidence. The official documentation does not promise min / max number of concurrent tasks a queue can perform.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the reference for GCD:

> Concurrent queues (also known as a type of global dispatch queue)
>   execute one or more tasks concurrently, but tasks are still started in
>   the order in which they were added to the queue. The currently
>   executing tasks run on distinct threads that are managed by the
>   dispatch queue. The exact number of tasks executing at any given point
>   is variable and depends on system conditions.

The system automatically (and dynamically) determines how many tasks to execute simultaneously.  Among other things it's based on battery state, # of cores, system load, etc.

See [Dispatch Queues](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html) for more information.